# Is possible to make a macro in google spreadsheet to execute a python code?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Personally i feel more confortable making a script in python and there are more libraries to use than a macro. But if there is no option..
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api

Comment: I now how to connect python with google spreadsheet, but not the other way around. I want if you click a button in google spreadsheet, run the python script.

Comment: Well do you know if that’s possible?

Comment: Authentication is a bit of a pain when interacting with python. To some degree you can work around this by using colab, but it's still anothing thing to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue can be solved by using an `onOpen(e)` trigger and by hosting your `python script` on Google Cloud.

**1. Use the `onOpen(e)` trigger**

The `onOpen(e)` trigger is used to create the menu `MY MENU` in your Spreadsheet each time the Spreadsheet opens. Moreover, the submenu item `TRIGGER THE PYTHON SCRIPT` will have the function `runScript()` associated with it and each time you click it, that function will be run.

[image: onOpen(e) behavior]

The above behavior can be achieved by using this snippet in Apps Script

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('MY MENU')
      .addItem('TRIGGER THE PYTHON SCRIPT', 'runScript')
      .addToUi();
}
```

**2. Host your Python script on Google Cloud**

You should host your Python Script in Google Cloud as a `Cloud Function` and run the code.

The `runScript()` is the function triggered by `TRIGGER THE PYTHON SCRIPT` menu from above and the snippet looks something like this.

```
function runScript() {
  var params = {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': {
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload': '{"name":"Name"}'
    }
  };
  var pyScript = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://YOUR_REGION-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME', params);
}
```

**Note:** You *might* have to change the `params` based on your script and your desired actions.

**Reference**

- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);
- [Apps Script UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app);
- [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could run a script yourselves and communicate with the spreadsheet through the API, but as far as I know, you have to use Apps Script to run scripts in the spreadsheet.

[Google Sheets API Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)
[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)